# UIScrollView touch handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm reading the following about UIScrollView from Apple UIScrollView Class Reference Documentation:

> Because a scroll view has no scroll
>   bars, it must know whether a touch
>   signals an intent to scroll versus an
>   intent to track a subview in the
>   content. To make this determination,
>   it temporarily intercepts a touch-down
>   event by starting a timer and, before
>   the timer fires, seeing if the
>   touching finger makes any movement. If
>   the timer fires without a significant
>   change in position, the scroll view
>   sends tracking events to the touched
>   subview of the content view. If the
>   user then drags their finger far
>   enough before the timer elapses, the
>   scroll view cancels any tracking in
>   the subview and performs the scrolling
>   itself. Subclasses can override the
>   touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:,
>   pagingEnabled, and
>   touchesShouldCancelInContentView:
>   methods (which are called by the
>   scroll view) to affect how the scroll
>   view handles scrolling gestures.

I don't understand the sentence starting with "If the user then drags their finger far enough before the timer elapses..."  I thought the timer already fired according to the previous sentence.  Is it talking about another timer in this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's confusing. I believe there are 2 possible behaviors depending on whether your scrollView has the `delaysContentTouches` property set (and or the `canCancelContentTouches` property is set)

If `delaysContentTouches` is set:

When the user taps the scroll view it temporarily intercepts a touch-down event by starting a timer and, before the timer fires, seeing if the touching finger makes any movement. If the timer fires without a significant change in position, the scroll view sends tracking events to the touched subview of the content view. If the user drags their finger far enough before the timer elapses, the scroll view begins scrolling.

If the timer has fired:

If `canCancelContentTouches` is set the scroll view cancels and touches passed to its subviews and begins scrolling. Otherwise, no scrolling.

If timer has not expired before the user drags his/her finger, scrolling happens.

I think I got that right... (someone might want to double-check)

HTH